# Modify text alignment in a JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, alignment, renderer

I have found a way to allocate the cell in a table, which seems to be a `Component`

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(
        TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        //  add custom rendering here

        return c;
    }
};
```

In the code, `c` is the Component, but I cannot find a method in `Component` to modify text alignment. Anything wrong about this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DefaultTableCellRenderer` for that purposes, it has `setHorizontalAlignment()` method :

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0,Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
         Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
         int align = DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER;
         if(condition){
             align = DefaultTableCellRenderer.LEFT;
         }
        ((DefaultTableCellRenderer)tableCellRendererComponent).setHorizontalAlignment(align);
         return tableCellRendererComponent;
    }
};
t.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

`COLUMN` is target column, `condition` is condition for switching.

Comment: Can you approach be applied to single cells, rather than a whole column or row?

Answer (score 4):

`(J)Component` havent this method(s) implemented in API

there are two ways

1. by casting `(J)Component` to `JLabel`
2. set this value for `class` managed by `getColumnClass`

.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer stringRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)
     table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
stringRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Comment: I failed in doing `(JLabel)c.**`. Eclipse turned me down. Any clue?

Comment: you can to cast two ways 1.  `JLabel label = (JLabel) c;` as next line and from `Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);`, then `returns label` instead of `return c;`, 2 cast inside code, when is really necessary `((JLabel) c).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);` rest of `prepareRenderer` stays unchanged

Comment: I tried your code, seems I can not cast 'c' to `JLabel`, while casting it to `DefaultTableCellRenderer` is feasible.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make a conclusion.

For this specifiec problem, we can divide it into two:

1. allocate the cell
2. agjust its alignment

To allocate the cell, my originally way and the way alex2410 should be both useful.

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    public Component prepareRenderer(
        TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
    {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

        //  add custom rendering here

        return c;
    }
};
```

another

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
             JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
         Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);

         //  add custom rendering here

         return c;
    }
};
t.getColumnModel().getColumn(COLUMN).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

And for alignment, the only method I found useful is:

```
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)c).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.center);
```

In mKorbel's suggestion, you can cast the `Component` c to  `JLabel`, but I failed to to that.